# Stuck with Taylor expansion of $f(x+x')$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I know that the Taylor series of $f(x)$ around $a$ is given by:

$$f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+f''(a)\frac{(x-a)^2}{2}+\dots=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a) }{n!} (x-a)^n$$

In my textbook I see the following formula for 
$f(x+x')$ which I however don't understand:

$$f(x+x')=f(x)+f'(x)x' +\frac{f''(x)}{2}(x')^2+\dots=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!} (x')^n $$

I don't understand how they obtained this formula. Can someone explain me that?

Comment: The two formulas both say the same thing; only the names are different.  What is called $a$ in the first one is called $x$ in the second one, and what is called $x-a$ in the first is called $x'$ in the second.

Comment: it would have been better if $x'$ were replaced by $h$ (as in traditional texts). But perhaps your text is trying to use a symbol similar to $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite your original formula, using $t$ instead of $x$:
$$
f(t)=f(a)+f'(a)(t-a)+f''(a)\frac{(t-a)^2}{2}+\ldots=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(a) }{n!} (t-a)^n.
$$
Now, let $t = x + x'$:
$$
f(x + x')=f(a)+f'(a)(x + x'-a)+f''(a)\frac{(x + x'-a)^2}{2}+\ldots=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(a) }{n!} (x + x'-a)^n
$$
Last, take $a = x$:
\begin{align*}
f(x + x')&=f(x)+f'(x)(x + x'-x)+f''(x)\frac{(x + x'-x)^2}{2}+\ldots\\
&= f(x)+f'(x)x'+f''(x)\frac{x'^2}{2}+\ldots\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!} (x')^n.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks I see. Isn't it however strange to center your Taylor series around $x$?

Comment: @user104662 Why, it's just a name? Centering the Taylor series around $WinnieThePooh$ would be kind of strange, but $x$ is a perfectly normal name for a variable.

Comment: @user104662 Not at all! This new formula writes $f$ of "$x$ plus a small change $x'$" in terms of $f(x)$ and the successive derivatives. If you ever used linear approximation to approximate $\sqrt{17}$, this is the same idea: $\sqrt{17}\approx \sqrt{16} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{16}} = 4 + \frac{1}{8} = \frac{33}{8}$. It's useful if you know how to evaluate $f$ and its derivatives at $x$, but maybe you can't evaluate $f$ precisely at $f(x + x')$.